# How to mount a persistent volume on a Deployment/Pod using PersistentVolumeClaim?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, persistent-volume-claims

I am trying to mount a persistent volume on pods (via a deployment).

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: ...
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /app/folder
          name: volume
      volumes:
      - name: volume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: volume-claim
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: volume-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
```

However, the pod stays in "ContainerCreating" status and the events show the following error message.

```
Unable to mount volumes for pod "podname": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach or mount for pod "namespace"/"podname". list of unmounted volumes=[volume]. list of unattached volumes=[volume]
```

I verified that the persistent volume claim is ok and bound to a persistent volume.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you doing this locally or via any cloud provider?

Comment: @paltaa the cluster is on GKE

Comment: How many replicas are in your `Deployment`?

Comment: @znat you seem to have a problem with GKE storageClass, do a kubectl describe sc, also check if the persistent volume is provisioned with kubectl get pv, then describe it with kubectl describe pv <your-pv> and post any events

Answer (score 3):

When you create a `PVC` without specifying a `PV` or type of `StorageClass` in GKE clusters it will fall back to default option:

- `StorageClass: standard`
- `Provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd`
- `Type: pd-standard`

Please take a look on official documentation: [Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes engine persistent volumes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes)

There could be a lot of circumstances that can produce error message encountered.

As it's unknown how many replicas are in your deployment as well as number of nodes and how pods were scheduled on those nodes, I've tried to reproduce your issue and I encountered the same error with following steps (GKE cluster was freshly created to prevent any other dependencies that might affect the behavior).

**Steps**:

- Create a PVC
- Create a Deployment with `replicas > 1`
- Check the state of pods
- Additional links

#### Create a PVC

Below is example `YAML` definition of a `PVC` the same as yours:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: volume-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
```

After applying above definition please check if it created successfully. You can do it by using below commands:

- `$ kubectl get pvc volume-claim`
- `$ kubectl get pv`
- `$ kubectl describe pvc volume-claim`
- `$ kubectl get pvc volume-claim -o yaml`

#### Create a Deployment with `replicas > 1`

Below is example `YAML` definition of deployment with `volumeMounts` and `replicas` > 1:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1 
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ubuntu-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ubuntu
  replicas: 10 # amount of pods must be > 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ubuntu
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ubuntu
        image: ubuntu
        command:
        - sleep
        - "infinity"
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /app/folder
          name: volume
      volumes:
      - name: volume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: volume-claim
```

Apply it and wait for a while.

#### Check the state of pods

You can check the state of pods with below command:

`$ kubectl get pods -o wide`

Output of above command:

```sh
NAME                      READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE     IP            NODE                              
ubuntu-deployment-2q64z   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          4m27s   <none>        gke-node-1  
ubuntu-deployment-4tjp2   1/1     Running             0          4m27s   10.56.1.14    gke-node-2   
ubuntu-deployment-5tn8x   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          4m27s   <none>        gke-node-1   
ubuntu-deployment-5tn9m   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          4m27s   <none>        gke-node-3  
ubuntu-deployment-6vkwf   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          4m27s   <none>        gke-node-1  
ubuntu-deployment-9p45q   1/1     Running             0          4m27s   10.56.1.12    gke-node-2  
ubuntu-deployment-lfh7g   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          4m27s   <none>        gke-node-3  
ubuntu-deployment-qxwmq   1/1     Running             0          4m27s   10.56.1.13    gke-node-2 
ubuntu-deployment-r7k2k   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          4m27s   <none>        gke-node-3   
ubuntu-deployment-rnr72   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          4m27s   <none>        gke-node-3
```

Take a look on above output:

- 3 pods are in `Running` state
- 7 pods are in `ContainerCreating` state

**All of the `Running` pods are located on the same `gke-node-2`**

You can get more detailed information why pods are in `ContainerCreating` state by:

`$ kubectl describe pod NAME_OF_POD_WITH_CC_STATE`

The `Events` part in above command shows:

```sh
Events:
  Type     Reason              Age                From                                             Message
  ----     ------              ----               ----                                             -------
  Normal   Scheduled           14m                default-scheduler                                Successfully assigned default/ubuntu-deployment-2q64z to gke-node-1
  Warning  FailedAttachVolume  14m                attachdetach-controller                          Multi-Attach error for volume "pvc-7d756147-6434-11ea-a666-42010a9c0058" Volume is already used by pod(s) ubuntu-deployment-qxwmq, ubuntu-deployment-9p45q, ubuntu-deployment-4tjp2
  Warning  FailedMount         92s (x6 over 12m)  kubelet, gke-node-1  Unable to mount volumes for pod "ubuntu-deployment-2q64z_default(9dc28e95-6434-11ea-a666-42010a9c0058)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach or mount for pod "default"/"ubuntu-deployment-2q64z". list of unmounted volumes=[volume]. list of unattached volumes=[volume default-token-dnvnj]
```

Pod cannot pass `ContainerCreating` state because of failed mounting of a `volume`. Mentioned `volume` is already used by other pods on a different node.

> **ReadWriteOnce:** The Volume can be mounted as read-write by a single node.

#### Additional links

Please take a look at: [Cloud.google.com: Access modes of persistent volumes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes#access_modes).

There is detailed answer on topic of access mode: [Stackoverflow.com: Why can you set multiple accessmodes on a persistent volume](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60308557)

As it's unknown what you are trying to achieve please take a look on comparison between Deployments and Statefulsets: [Cloud.google.com: Persistent Volume: Deployments vs statefulsets](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes#deployments_vs_statefulsets).

Answer (score 1):

If doing this in a cloud provider, the storageClass object will create the respective volume for your persistent volume claim.

If you are trying to do this locally on minikube or in a self managed kubernetes cluster, you need to manually create the storageClass that will provide the volumes for you, or create it manually like this example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: task-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
```

The hostPath variable will mount this data in the current pod node.

Comment: Thanks, The cluster is in GKE